# Webpack is showing wrong eslint linting errors

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, eslint

When I start my dev server webpack console some linting errors that don't exist actually. You can see code given below error is saying "Strings must use singlequote" but actually in code there is no single quotation used.

controller.js

```
 const columnSelectorCtrl = ($scope, $rootScope, $modal, columnSelectionApi) => {
      const openSelectionPopup = () => {
        const saveSelectionHandler = () => {
          if ($scope.isColumnSelectionToBeSaved) {
            const selectionPayload = {
              pageId: $scope.pageId,
              selectedColumnIds: _.pluck(
                _.filter($scope.columnsList, (column) => column.show), ['id']
              ),
            };

            columnSelectionApi.save(selectionPayload);
          }
        };
        $scope.columnSelectPopup = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'columnSelectTemplate.html',
          controller: columnSelectorCtrl,
          scope: $scope,
        });

        return $scope.columnSelectPopup.result.finally(saveSelectionHandler);
      };

      const isColumnShown = (column) => column.show;
      const isAnyColumnShown = (columnsList) => columnsList.some(isColumnShown);
      const mapShownStateWithDefault = (column) =>
        (column.show = column.show_by_default);
      const showDefaultColumnSelection = (columnsList) =>
        columnsList.forEach(mapShownStateWithDefault);

      const determineToShowDefaultSelection = (columnsList) => {
        $scope.$watch(
          'columnsList',
          function(newList, oldList) {
            console.log('config changed');
            if (newList && !isAnyColumnShown(newList)) {
              showDefaultColumnSelection(newList);
            }
          },
          true
        );
      };

      $scope.closeSelectionPopup = () => $scope.columnSelectPopup.close();

      (function initialize() {
        $scope.openColumnsPopup = openSelectionPopup;
        determineToShowDefaultSelection($scope.columnsList);
      })();
    };

    export {
      columnSelectorCtrl,
    };
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that eslint is linting the transpiled javascript instead of your original one?

Comment: I run this code using npm start. Do you have any solution how i can fix this ?

Comment: That really depends on your webpack configuration. Hard to say without seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

babel was transpiling code before eslint start scanning.

```
    loaders: [
      // Javascript
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
          fix: true,
          quiet: true,
          failOnError: true,
        },
       {
        enforce: "post",
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
          // directory for faster rebuilds.
          cacheDirectory: true,
        },
        options: {
          fix: true,
          quiet: true,
          failOnError: false,
        },
      },
      },
```

load eslint-loader in preloader property

```
 preLoaders: [
      // Javascript
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
          fix: true,
          quiet: true,
          failOnError: true,
        },
      },
    ],
```